# Counting the number of times a counter increments in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234], 'year':['2017', '2017', '2018', '2018', '2018'], 'count_to_today':[1, 2, 3, 3, 4})
```

And I need to count how many times `count_to_today` happens cumulatively in each year per `id`. i.e.

```
counts = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234], 'year':['2017', '2017', '2018', '2018', '2018'], 'count_to_today':[1, 2, 1, 1, 2]})
```

I.e. I have a running count since the beginning of time, and I want to count the number of times it increments cumulatively per year.

I'm a bit confused about how to do this. I know I need to groupby `id` and `year` but I can't figure out how to get `.count()` or `.value_counts()` to give me the counts per year.

Comment: Not same question ask before?

Comment: No - I realised that I'd made a mistake in my output specification.

Comment: I kept on getting a notification telling me to wait before accepting an answer.

Comment: @TomKealy You can accept an answer 15 minutes after asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your previous question, but use `cumsum` instead:

```
df.count_to_today.diff().ne(0).groupby([df.id, df.year]).cumsum()

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
Name: count_to_today, dtype: float64
```

---

```
df['count_to_today'] = (
    df.count_to_today.diff().ne(0).groupby([df.id, df.year]).cumsum().astype(int))
df

     id  year  count_to_today
0  1234  2017               1
1  1234  2017               2
2  1234  2018               1
3  1234  2018               1
4  1234  2018               2
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I made a mistake in my output example and didn't know what to do once people had answered the question.